# A Database Error Occurred You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this thing happens only in localhost

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GETDATE())' at line 1

> SELECT MAX(RIGHT(DaftarNomor,2)) AS kd_max FROM TDaftarTelepon_Coba
> WHERE DaftarTanggal= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/daftarpasien/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 691

here is my code:

```
$date= date("Y-m-d");
$kodeunit = $this->input->post('UnitKode');
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(RIGHT(DaftarNomor,2)) AS kd_max FROM TDaftarTelepon_Coba WHERE DaftarTanggal= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())");
$kd = "";
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($q->result() as $k) {
        $tmp = ((int)$k->kd_max) + 1;
        $kd = sprintf("%02s", $tmp);
    }
} else {
    $kd = "01";
}
```

Comment: There is no getdate() in mysql try now() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `DATE()` function to get a timestamp date:

```
$q = $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
        MAX(RIGHT(DaftarNomor,2)) AS kd_max 
    FROM 
        TDaftarTelepon_Coba 
    WHERE 
        DaftarTanggal = DATE(date)
");
```